# Object Type xxx is not found in schema

Tags: react-native, realm

Firstly, i defined the TestSchema first, and create "let realm = new Realm({schema: [TestSchema]})",and the result for {realm.objects('Test').length} is right. 
When i try to add more schemas into realm, e.g.'let realm = new Realm({schema:[TestSchema, CarSchema, PersonSchema]})', it shows the wrong msg. "Object Type Car is not found in schema". I was wondering what's going on here.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet that shows how you define the schema?

Comment: Hey, Tayschrenn. I have solved this problem. I've put all these schema definitions in one file, say realm.js, and export these schemas. I found it worked. I can call the file anywhere i want to operate the realm db now. U can see this, https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js

Answer (score 1):

Put all these schema definitions in one file, say realm.js, and export these schemas.

You can check this.
https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js

Hoho, we can call the realm db anywhere we want.