# Realm.open vs new Realm

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

In the context of a React Native app, using Realm locally only (so no realm object server for now). What is the difference between opening a realm using 
`Realm.open({schema: [Car, Person]})` and creating a new Realm instance with `new Realm({schema: [Car, Person]});` When should I use one or the other?

Looks like `Realm.open` is just a callback to make sure the syncronisation is done, so only needed for synced Realms?

So far this is what I found:

### Realm.open:

According to the [doc reference](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/2.2.0/api/Realm.html#.open) `Realm.open` means *"Open a Realm asynchronously with a promise. If the Realm is synced, it will be fully synchronized before it is available."* It's the way shown in the [js docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#realms)

### new Realm:

According to the constructor in the [doc reference](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/2.2.0/api/Realm.html), `new Realm` will *Create a new Realm instance [...]. If a Realm does not yet exist [...], then this constructor will create it. Otherwise, the instance will access the existing Realm*

In the React example they use new: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js

Answer (score 8):

Is there any specific usecase you have in mind ? Otherwise within react native i havent had to use Realm.open so far.
They way i've seen most people approach the architecture is to have a file named
realm.js
where the schemas are defined and a new Realm is exported like so

```
class ShoppingCartItem extends Realm.Object{}
ShoppingCartItem.schema = {
    name: 'ShoppingCartItem',
    primaryKey: 'ordernumber',
    properties: {
        ordernumber: 'string',
        quantity: 'int',
        unitPrice: 'double'
    }
}

export default new Realm({schema: [User, LastViewedProduct, ShoppingCartItem]});
```

and then have another file called realmTasks.js where you import that realm object and define actions on it. If you need the realm object in the local state to register changes you can define a callback and give it the realm reference as an argument such as

```
export function addShoppingCartItem(ordernumber, quantity, unitPrice, callback){
    realm.write(() => {
        realm.create('ShoppingCartItem', {
            ordernumber: ordernumber,
            quantity: quantity,
            unitPrice: unitPrice
        });
    })
    return callback(realm);
}
```

I'm not sure if this completely answers your question or is useful to you at all but i hope this gives you a hint :)

Comment: I'm also using "new Realm" as you mention, also like in https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js

Before I was using Realm.open but I started seeing some ["Object Type xxx is not found in schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126389/object-type-xxx-is-not-found-in-schema) problems on Android, that's why I changed.

Comment: @XaviA. I'm using `new Realm` as per the link you gave and the answer above however I would like to use one of the async open methods. Are you able to provide code as to how you used `.open` in a React Native app and were able to access the realm from all of your screens?

Comment: In my case I'm using the "new Realm" approach without issues. What do you mean with "I would like to use one of the async open methods?"

I've updated my answer here with some more code for the "new Realm approach":  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46566527/open-realm-js-defined-in-another-js-file/46610193#46610193 

Probably replacing 
`export default new Realm({schema: schemasArray});`
by 
`export default Realm.open({schema: schemasArray});` works but I haven't tested it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [docs](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#synchronously-opening-realms) can completely cover your question.
So using sync approach (`const realm = new Realm()`) is more simple and appropriate for exporting realm as a module, but it's still preferable to get promise `Realm.open()` and handle realm instance when schema migration and sync from remote 
 server are completed.