# It it better to open a global Realm object or use Realm.open everytime? Real.open vs new Realm

Tags: javascript, react-native, realm

In [Realm introduction](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#introduction) for React Native, there's no global usage of Realm. When Realm needs to be used, it's always called through `Realm.open()`.

What is the correct way of doing it? Seems like opening a new Realm each time may be inneficient, but there's no comment on the mechanism of Realm.open. It might be cacheing things, I don't know.

On the other side, `new Realm()` can be used and stored in a way that's accessible throughout the entire application. However, its creation is not assynchronous like `Real.open()` and I've run through some delay problems on using this technique (it can be made assynchronous too, though)

I'm trying to do it globally. I'm making the initial query to show in  list view right at the `componentWillMount()`. It takes some time for the list view to initially appear and fr some reason it only displays some objects and then takes some seconds to display the rest.

I'm doing as seen in [Realm.open vs new Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668497/realm-open-vs-new-realm) on the link https://github.com/realm/realm-js/blob/master/examples/ReactExample/components/realm.js

Comment: Depends on whether you are using it strictly locally or with the Realm Platform / Realm Cloud stuff

Comment: @EpicPandaForce totally loca, but what would be the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Performance wise, if you plan to have a single realm schema, I would recommend to keep a global Realm. e.g:

```
Realm.open(mySchema).then(realm => {
  this.setState({realm})
})
```

I think you just need to care about opening and closing realm if you plan to have multiple schemas. e.g:

```
Realm.open(mySchema).then(realm => {
  //do stuff
  realm.close()
})
```